# How to completely remove anything related to Firefox

Tags: 18.04, firefox, malware, firefox-extensions

My Ubuntu 18.04 device has been infected. there have been fraudulent bank transactions. I need to clean my Firefox completely.

Please, help me with steps to completely remove any file related to Firefox.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/68461/how-safe-are-firefox-addons-from-official-mozilla-org-site

Answer (score 0):

Start with this: `sudo apt-get purge firefox`

Here is a link that shows you how to also remove any assocaited files that may still be lingering: 
[Remove Firefox and all related folders](https://technastic.com/uninstall-and-install-firefox-on-ubuntu/)